# Why is the sum of my blackjack score not working properlly?

Tags: java, arrays, random, switch-statement, blackjack

I am quite new at programing, and i have been trying to create a Simple BlackJack game on java, however i am having issues with the score counting.

Sometimes it recognizes the actual card value and works fine, others it just defines a random value and messesup with the whole game. i have used numbers from 1 to 52 to randomly define cards into an "array" and so set them as a "jlabel" as the game flows. the score counting is set inside an "switch" which defines the value of each card.

Here is my code please help me:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
card= new int[53];
Amount = Double.parseDouble(Apuesta);
Apuesta = jTextField1.getText();      
BilleteraT = Double.toString(Billetera-Amount); 
jTextField2.setText(BilleteraT);


if (Apuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por Favor, ingrese una apuesta");}

else {
step2 = false;
if(step1=true){
Apuesta = jTextField1.getText();
Amount = Double.parseDouble(Apuesta);
Billetera=Billetera-Amount;
BilleteraT = Double.toString(Billetera); 
jTextField2.setText(BilleteraT);}


while(Amount <= Billetera && Amount!=0 || Billetera>=0&& Amount!=0){

jButton5.setVisible(false);
jButton5.invalidate();    

for (k=1;k<=6;k++){    
card[k]=rnd.nextInt(53)+1;

switch (k){
    case 1: p1= card[1];
    case 2: p2= card[2];
    case 3: c1= card[3];
    case 4: c2= card[4];
    case 5: p3= card[5];
    case 6: c3= card[6];}}

jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+p1+".png")));
jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+p2+".png")));
jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+c1+".png")));
jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));

for (k=1;k<=53;k++){      
switch(k){
    case 1:case 14:case 27:case 40:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=2;} if(k==p2){scorep2=2;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=2;} if(k==c2){scorec2=2;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=2;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=2;}
    break;
    case 2:case 15:case 28:case 41:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=3;} if(k==p2){scorep2=3;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=3;} if(k==c2){scorec2=3;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=3;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=3;}
    break;
    case 3:case 16:case 29:case 42:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=4;} if(k==p2){scorep2=4;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=4;} if(k==c2){scorec2=4;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=4;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=4;}
    break;
    case 4:case 17:case 30:case 43:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=5;} if(k==p2){scorep2=5;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=5;} if(k==c2){scorec2=5;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=5;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=5;}
    break;
    case 5:case 18:case 31:case 44:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=6;} if(k==p2){scorep2=6;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=6;} if(k==c2){scorec2=6;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=6;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=6;} 
    break;
    case 6:case 19:case 32:case 45:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=7;} if(k==p2){scorep2=7;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=7;} if(k==c2){scorec2=7;}    

    if (k==p3){scorep3=7;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=7;} 
    break;
    case 7:case 20:case 33:case 46:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=8;} if(k==p2){scorep2=8;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=8;} if(k==c2){scorec2=8;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=8;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=8;} 
    break;
    case 8:case 21:case 34:case 47:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=9;} if(k==p2){scorep2=9;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=9;} if(k==c2){scorec2=9;}    

    if (k==p3){scorep3=9;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=9;} 
    break;
    case 9:case 11:case 12:case 13:case 22:case 24:case 25:case 26:case 35:case 37:case 38:case 39:case 48:case 50:case 51:case 52:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=10;} if(k==p2){scorep2=10;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=10;}  if(k==c2){scorec2=10;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=10;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=10;} 
    break;
    case 10:case 23:case 36:case 49:
    if(k==p1){scorep1=1;} if(k==p2){scorep2=1;}
    if(k==c1){scorec1=1;} if(k==c2){scorec2=1;}

    if (k==p3){scorep3=1;}
    if (k==c3){scorec3=1;} 
    break;}}

    scoreP=scorep1+scorep2;
    scoreC=scorec1;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jTextField4.setText(score2); 
    step1=true;}

    if(Amount!=0&&Billetera>0 || Billetera<=0 ){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No podeis apostar lo que no tenes!!!");} 


}

}                                        
/** PEDIR BUTTON  */
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

if (step1=true && Billetera>0){

    if (step2=true && Billetera>0){
    p4=rnd.nextInt(53)+1;
     for (k=1;k<=53;k++){      
switch(k){
    case 1:case 14:case 27:case 40:    
    if (k==p4){scorep4=2;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=2;}
    break;
    case 2:case 15:case 28:case 41:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=3;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=3;}
    break;
    case 3:case 16:case 29:case 42:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=4;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=4;}
    break;
    case 4:case 17:case 30:case 43:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=5;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=5;}
    break;
    case 5:case 18:case 31:case 44:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=6;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=6;} 
    break;
    case 6:case 19:case 32:case 45:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=7;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=7;} 
    break;
    case 7:case 20:case 33:case 46:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=8;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=8;} 
    break;
    case 8:case 21:case 34:case 47:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=9;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=9;} 
    break;
    case 9:case 11:case 12:case 13:case 22:case 24:case 25:case 26:case 35:case 37:case 38:case 39:case 48:case 50:case 51:case 52:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=10;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=10;} 
    break;
    case 10:case 23:case 36:case 49:
    if (k==p4){scorep4=1;}
    if (k==c4){scorec4=1;} 
    break;}}
    scoreP=scorep4+scoreP;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+p4+".png")));
    }

    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+p3+".png")));

    scoreP=scorep3+scoreP;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    step2 = true;


    if (scoreP==21){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Felicitaciones, Ganaste!");
    Billetera=Billetera+Amount*2;
    BilleteraT = Double.toString(Billetera); 
    jTextField2.setText(BilleteraT);

    res=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Queres intentar otra vez?");

    if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sin problemas, ingrese nueva Aposta");
    jButton5.setVisible(true);
    jButton5.validate();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    scoreC=0;
    scoreP=0;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jTextField4.setText(score2);} 

    else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bueno, Hasta la proxima! Adios");
    System.exit(0);

    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Respuesta Invalida");}}       

    if (scoreP>21){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Uhh,Pasaste, mas suerte en la proxima!");

    res=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Queres intentar otra vez?");
    if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sin problemas, ingrese nueva Aposta");
    jButton5.setVisible(true);
    jButton5.validate();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    scoreC=0;
    scoreP=0;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jTextField4.setText(score2);}

    else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bueno, Hasta la proxima! Adios");
    System.exit(0);

    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Respuesta Invalida");}}

}
}                                        
/** PLANTARSE BUTTON  */
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Okay, Mi turno!");

if (step1=true&&Billetera>0){
 scoreC=scorec2+scoreC;
 score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
 jTextField4.setText(score2);
 jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+c2+".png")));

 if(scoreC<=16){resc="hit";

 while(resc.equals("hit")){

 jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/"+c3+".png")));
 scoreC=scorec3+scoreC;
 score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
 jTextField4.setText(score2);

 if(scoreC<=16){resc="hit";}
 if(scoreC>16){resc="stand";}}

 }else if(scoreC>16){resc="stand";}

 while(resc.equals("stand")){

if (scoreC>scoreP&&scoreC<=21){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Gano yo, mas suerte en la proxima!");

    res=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Queres intentar otra vez?");
    if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sin problemas, ingrese nueva Aposta");
    jButton5.setVisible(true);
    jButton5.validate();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    scoreC=0;
    scoreP=0;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jTextField4.setText(score2); }

    else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bueno, Hasta la proxima! Adios");
    System.exit(0);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Respuesta Invalida");}}

if(scoreP>scoreC&&scoreP<=21){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Felicitaciones, Ganaste!");
    Billetera=Billetera+Amount*2;
    BilleteraT = Double.toString(Billetera); 
    jTextField2.setText(BilleteraT);

    res=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Queres intentar otra vez?");
    if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sin problemas, ingrese nueva Aposta");
    jButton5.setVisible(true);
    jButton5.validate();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    scoreC=0;
    scoreP=0;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jTextField4.setText(score2);}

    else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bueno, Hasta la proxima! Adios");
    System.exit(0);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Respuesta Invalida");}}


if(scoreP==scoreC&&scoreP<=21){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Es un Empate!");

    res=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Queres jugar de nuevo?");
    if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sin problemas, ingrese nueva Aposta");
    jButton5.setVisible(true);
    jButton5.validate();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    scoreC=0;
    scoreP=0;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jTextField4.setText(score2); } 

    else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bueno, Hasta la proxima! Adios");
    System.exit(0);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Respuesta Invalida");}
    }

}
} 
}                                        
 /** DESISTIR BUTTON  */
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (step1=true && Billetera>0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bueno, mas suerte en la proxima!");

    res=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Queres intentar otra vez?");
    if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sin problemas, ingrese nueva Aposta");
    jButton5.setVisible(true);
    jButton5.validate();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/back.png")));
    jLabel11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    scoreC=0;
    scoreP=0;
    score1 = Double.toString(scoreP);
    score2 = Double.toString(scoreC);
    jTextField3.setText(score1);
    jTextField4.setText(score2); }

    else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bueno, Hasta la proxima! Adios");
    System.exit(0);
    }else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Respuesta Invalida");}}    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Next please try to post a nicely formatted [mcve] because that much code is hard to scan and thus it's easy to miss something (e.g. I have the feeling most of that UI code is irrelevant to the question and the broken formatting makes it hard to see the individual code blocks). Then please also tell us where exactly the error happens (what you do to produce it etc.) . Also, did you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: On a side note: try to not use that many magic numbers, e.g. here `case 1:case 14:case 27:case 40:` - it's hard to see what those numbers mean and that cas introduce a plethora of subtle bugs (e.g. one number being used where another should be but you don't see it right away).

Comment: best line of action would be to clean up your code and exchange all variable names that aren't easily understandable (like p3 c2 etc.) with names that represent their meaning and declare int variables that represent your cases. after doing this your code should be a lot clearer and you might even find the error this way if not come back and im sure someone will help you

Comment: Your very first `switch (k)` statement has many `case` statements with no `break;` statements in them. Is that intentional?  Or did you want each case’s execution to fall through to the following cases?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a compiler near by, but here's an error I saw by reading  your code.

Where you are declaring:
card= new int[53];
It's creating an array from 0-52 which is actually 53 values, so it's assuming you have 53 cards.
The proper declaration would be:
card= new int[52];
Because that way it's making an array from 0-51 which is 52 values.

Comment: Actually it's even worse: only indices 1 to 6 are ever set and used, so the array will contain 47 unused elements with value 0.